# Standalone Instance, or Deployed War?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

Why would you deploy a WAR onto a web server such as tomcat, as opposed to running it standalone?

Are there benefits as to deploying as a .war opposed to running the instance standalone?

I cant seem to find any reason why it's better to deploy a web app, then it is to run it stand alone.

Is war deployment just standard practice?

Does the size of user-base have anything to do with it?

Is it a per application basis?

Is it just admin preference?

The reason I am asking these questions is I have a webservice that I have the option to deploy my war file to tomcat, or to run it standalone.  Is there a general practice on to why you would use one over the other?  There seems to be little reason why, and more of just do.

I don't agree with the practice of "It's always been done this way..."

If anyone could shine some light on when to use one over the other, and why it's superior to do so, that would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several (really) reasons. One very limiting comes to mind: sockets. If you have standalone apps, each will have its own port. Everytime you deploy a new one, you'll have to worry about firewall, proxying and network related stuff. Also your clients may not be able to perform requests to some ports.

Comment: Good answer.  But...The applications we are running are for a corporations intranet. Firewall, proxying, portforwarding... etc are not really of concern.  Although with only needing one port, there is less maintenance that way.

Comment: Multiple ports don't bother you? Intranet it may be, but with a single application server, one hit solves it all. For one, two, three systems, many ports is ok. What happens when you have hundreds of them? Consider more advanced stuff, like clustering, load balancing, performance profiling, logging, security, naming, **integration between systems**. All of this an application server takes care for you, standards and patterns come to your aid. With standalone apps, you're on your own. Every new guy will have to learn it all from the tiniest bit. Need urgent help? Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will take care of all the HTTP stuff for you.  Things like HTTP request and response, sessions, and JSP.  Maybe this will help - http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ.

Comment: I understand what tomcat is, and what it does.

What I don't understand, is when you have an option to run an application standalone or deploy to tomcat, why would you choose one over the other.

Currently the software in question is a war deployed on tomcat.  The software is not required to be deployed, and can run a standalone instance. Why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: One reason to use tomcat is if you need to scale horizontally (cluster) or need to switch it behind a HttpD proxy.

Comment: Also tomcat will give you some stats on usage.  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one web site on one server then there is no difference... you could make that whole site a PowerPoint presentation and email it.